# Understanding the loss curves of LSTM

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently training a Multi-layer LSTM with EEG data for classification. I have a dataset comprising of 3315 training examples (not all independent, they have overlaps) per class and 4 classes. The design of the LSTM is built in this way. LSTM1 accepts inputs in the same direction as time, LSTM2 in the reverse direction. LSTM3 accepts outputs of the previous LSTMs concatenated together in the direction of time. The network uses an Adam Optimizer with learning rate 2*1e-5. I have also used dropout in the outputs of the LSTM cells with keep_probability=0.1. The loss and accuracy showed the following behavior (image below), which I am unable to comprehend. The top graph is loss and the bottom graph is accuracy. The loss is the cross-entropy loss. Each data frame is a sequence of 250 vectors, each of size 198. LSTM1 and 2 have 100 hidden neurons and LSTM3 has 200 hidden neurons (double the size due to concatenation).

[image: Upper graph is loss, below graph, is accuracy]

I feel that overfitting started somewhere in between epoch 100 and epoch 150. Is my conclusion correct? I am doubtful about it because the loss later on decreases. Should I run more epochs?

Do you have any suggestions to help improve the performance? I feel there is scope to increase performance because the data being EEG is sequential and a convolutional neural network when fed the exact same data gave an accuracy close to 68%. Any insight is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "LSTM2 accepts inputs in the reverse direction as time"? Why would you want to do such a thing? Why is LSTM3 doing what it is doing?

Comment: Which framework are you using to build your network? Which program/library produced those plots?

Comment: I suppose that by "100 hidden neurons" you mean the size of the hidden vector, that is the size of the memory of the cell, of the LSTM, right?

Comment: What exactly is a data frame in your case? You say "Each data frame is a sequence of 250 vectors, each of size 198.". What's the exact meaning of that? It's not clear what are these data frames and why they are composed of 250 vectors. Vectors of what?

Comment: You forgot to tell us which function the blue and red lines are describing? The loss in the _training_ and _validation_ datasets, respectively?

Comment: It seems that the blue line corresponds to the training set and the red dashed line to the test set. He's certainly having a good amount of overfitting, but I'd say it's not that bad, because the accuracy becomes stable on the test set. I'd train longer to see what happens, as it looks like the red loss could keep going down.